# Vite / Vue 3 : "require is not defined" when using image source as props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I switched from the Vue CLI to [Vite CLI](https://vitejs.dev/), and from the Composition API of Vue 3 to [SFC Script setup](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#sfc-script-setup) API.

#### How it previously worked for me

When I was using the official Vue CLI, I could import an image source by passing the filename of the path by the props :

```html
<template>
  <img :src="require(`@/assets/${imagePath}`)"/>
<template/>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    imagePath: { type: String },
  },
  setup() {
    // ...
  }
}
<script/>
```

And then call it like this :

```html
<template>
  <Image imagePath="icon.png" />
</template>
```

#### The error I get since I migrated to Vite

But since I migrated to the Vite CLI, I have an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". My file now use the script setup syntax and looks like this :

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  imagePath: { type: String },
})
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="require(`@/assets/${props.imagePath}`)"/>
</template>
```

[image: require is not define error]

#### What I tried

I already tried to import the file directly from the assets folder with a relative path, and it worked. But I cannot specify the path from props with the import statement.

```html
<script setup>
// Works but do not use the props, so the component is not reusable
import logo from "./../assets/logo.png"
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="logo"/>
</template>
```

```html
<script setup>
// Component is reusable but the import statement has illegal argument I guess
const props = defineProps({
  imagePath: { type: String },
})

import logo from `./../assets/${props.imagePath}`
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="logo"/>
</template>
```

I also tried the import statement in the template but it cannot even compile the code :

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  imagePath: { type: String },
})
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="import `./../assets/${props.iconPath}`" />
</template>
```

Am I missing something ? Maybe a plugin exists and can help me achieve this ?

Answer (score 53):

I also encountered this problem. I searched about this and found according to this [github issue comment](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1241#issuecomment-762367047),

> There should never be `require` in source code when using Vite. It's
> ESM only.

More about this on [Features | Vite - Static Assets](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#static-assets)

A bit of searching lead me to this Vue 3 code sample [link](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/399939287) that worked for me

```
<CarouselItem v-for="(item,index) of carouselData" :key="index">
 <img :src="getImageUrl(item.img_name)" />
</CarouselItem>
```

```
setup() {
  const getImageUrl = (name) => {
        return new URL(`../../lib/Carousel/assets/${name}`, import.meta.url).href
    }
  return { carouselData, getImageUrl }
}
```

Comment: Is this working for you when running a production build?

Comment: My bad - just in case someone stumbles upon this: I had a JS file in my assets folder that was causing trobles. Now with only .jpg and .svg files it works like a charm!

Comment: The link to `static assets` with Vite did it  for me.

Answer (score 14):

In case you're using `require.context`, the new way seems to be [glob import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import). Change your old statement from:

```
const locales = require.context("../../lang", true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
```

to:

```
const locales = import.meta.glob('../../lang/*.json')
```

**Edit**:

This also seems to replace `require`.

Comment: this resolved the error but i was using `require` to dynamically load an image and it __fails__ to load the image

Answer (score 2):

for those who will use static assets with vue + vite, they can use this method.

```
import imgUrl from '../../img/bgimg.jpg'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bgImage: imgUrl
    };
  },

};
```

then you can use it like this

```
<div class="ms-auto h-100 z-index-0 ms-n6"
    :style="{
    backgroundImage:
    'url(' +
    bgImage +
    ')',
    }"
></div>
```

Importing a static asset will return the resolved public URL when it is served:

```js
import imgUrl from './img.png'
document.getElementById('hero-img').src = imgUrl
```

For example, imgUrl will be `/img.png` during development, and become `/assets/img.2d8efhg.png` in the production build.

see also: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url

Answer (score 1):

Use a [watcher](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watcheffect) on the `imagePath` prop that dynamically imports the image, and updates a `ref` (bound to the `<img>.src`) with the result:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  imagePath: { type: String },
})

const logo = ref()
watchEffect(async () => {
  logo.value = (await import(/* @vite-ignore */ `../assets/${props.imagePath}`)).default
})
</script>

<template>
  <img :src="logo">
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-load-asset-url-dynamically?file=src/components/Image.vue)

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

If none of provided answers is not help (as in my case) - try to use `<slot/>` instead, as shown below:

```
//card component (child)
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

//services component (parent)
<template>
  <ServiceCard>
    <img src="@/assets/icons/service-1.svg" alt="svg image" />
  </ServiceCard>

  <ServiceCard>
    <img src="@/assets/icons/service-2.svg" alt="svg image" />
  </ServiceCard>
</template>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. I have a global function that gets the image path depending on product name. That's how I made it work.

Many thanks to @leipzy

```
export const getProductLogo = (cart) => {

  
  if (cart) {
    let im
    try {
      im = `../assets/img/cart/${cart}.png`
    } catch (err) {
      im = '../assets/img/default-logo.svg'
    }
    return new URL(`${im}`, import.meta.url).href
  }
}
```