# How to import image file in vueJs template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

using Vite I need to import image url for example with the way like this

```
 <svg :src="import('®/@material-icons/svg/1k/outline.svg')"></svg>
```

but instead of url I'm getting `src="[object Promise]"`
is there any ways to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `require`

```
<svg :src="require('®/@material-icons/svg/1k/outline.svg')"></svg>
```

Ensure to have the correct path for the file

Fore Vite

```
<svg :src="svgPath"></svg>

<script>
  async created(){
    this.svgPath = (await import("®/@material-icons/svg/1k/outline.svg")).default()
  }
  data(){
    return {svgPath:""}
  }
</script>
```

Comment: but require is not working with Vite

Comment: Edited. Please try. I came across with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696677/vite-vue-3-require-is-not-defined-when-using-image-source-as-props)

Comment: thank you, but seems vue render works synchronously and I cannot use await(
I'm getting 'await' is only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.
and I don't know is there any ways to change templates render type to async

Comment: I've updated the answer, give it a try

Comment: yep, thanks, that works, but that's a lot of code if compare with require using webpack, is there any plugins to make that shorter)?

Comment: You can make an utility function in a separate file, and pass the path as parameter and return the default value

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to work with images in Vitejs is to place images inside the `public` folder then use them without any import, Assume that we have a folder named `svg` inside the public one :

```html
<svg src="/svg/1k/outline.svg"></svg>
```

Or import it as module then bind it to the `src` attribute :

```html
<template>
  <svg :src="imgUrl"></svg>
</template>
<script setup>
   import imgUrl from '®/@material-icons/svg/1k/outline.svg'
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm using @material-icons/svg which are located in node_modules
seems the only problem I have is I have 30+ svgs and that's pretty hard to remember name of every variable using import every time in script((