# Vue dynamic img with mouseover

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I written vue code like that

```html
<template>
    <nav id="header-nav">
        <router-link to="/" class="logo">
            <img id='header-logo' :src="curlogo" 
            @mouseover="curlogo=logo_over" 
            @mouseleave="curlogo=logo"/>
        </router-link>
    </nav>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            logo: require("@/../public/logo.png"),
            logo_over: require("@/../public/logo_over.png"),
            curlogo: require("@/../public/logo.png"),
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

and it change img when i over mouse on img.
But, I rewrite vue code by `script setup`.
`template` code is same, and I change `script` code wlike that.

```js
<script setup>
const logo=require("@/../public/logo.png")
const logo_over=require("@/../public/logo_over.png")
let curlogo = logo
</script>
```

but... It is not work. How can I use mouseover with img?

Comment: what is the intended outcome? could you please explain ur logic in mouseover and mouseleave please?

Comment: @KickButtowski When I over the mouse, img's src is `logo`. When I leave the mouse, imgs's src is 'logo_over'.

Comment: just an experiment can you omit :src="curlogo" out from ur code?

Comment: @KickButtowski why not? And I need ref or reactive?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696677/vite-vue-3-require-is-not-defined-when-using-image-source-as-props) you can use a code like below:

```html
<template>
  <nav id="header-nav">
    <router-link to="/" class="logo">
      <img id='header-logo' :src="getImageUrl(curlogo)"
           @mouseover="logo='logo.svg'" @mouseout="logo='index.jpg'"/>
    </router-link>
  </nav>
</template>


<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";
const getImageUrl = (name) => {
  return new URL(`../assets/${name}`, import.meta.url).href
}
const logo=ref('index.jpg');
let curlogo = ref(logo)
</script>
```

You should change `../assets/${name}` and the name of images to your images paths and name.

Comment: I refer to your code, and It work well. thanks

Answer (score -1):

It is my final code, and it works well. thanks.

```html
<template>
    <nav id="header-nav">
        <router-link to="/" class="" >
            <img class="header-logo" :src="getImageUrl(curlogo)" @mouseover="curlogo=logo_over" @mouseout="curlogo=logo">
        </router-link>

    </nav>
</template>
    
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const getImageUrl = name => {
    return name
}
const logo = require("../assets/logo.png")
const logo_over = require("../assets/logo_over.png")
const curlogo = ref(logo);
</script>
```

Comment: You should not mix es6 and common js in one file. This leads to problems in some setups and is a bad style. Even if it works. Also the ˋgetImageUrlˋ is a non-sense function, as it only returns the passed value…

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).