# Vite doens't compile correctly JS in Laravel Breeze running on Homestead

Tags: laravel, vite, homestead, laravel-breeze

I have Laravel Breeze running on Homestead. I've noticed the the dropdown functionality from the menu is not working and checked the console log in the browser where I got:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined :build/assets/app-f35e98d6.js:1
```

I've checked the compiled JS file and it has something like this:

```js
window._=require("lodash");window.axios=require("axios");
```

My package.json looks like this:

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build --watch"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "^4.17.21"
    }
}
```

And this is the config file for vite

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({

    plugins: [

        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

And just in case if it is needed - composer.json

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.6",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.8",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.20",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "pestphp/pest": "^2.0",
        "pestphp/pest-plugin-laravel": "^2.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0",
        "vkovic/laravel-commando": "^0.2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I don't get any errors while running `npm run dev` or `npm run build`. I have tried running both from the `vagrant` and from my `home` (my OS is Linux), and still having the issue. I haven't edit any of the JS files that came with Breeze, and I haven't added any other JS.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71135980/2157656).

Basically it says that Vite doesn't compile `require` statements. So I've changed the content of `/resources/js/bootstrap.js` from

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

to

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```